# How to use filter() to remove all strings from a list with strings and numbers?

Tags: python, list, filter

I have a list for example

```
list = [1,2,3,'t',4,5,'fgt',6,7,'string']
```

and I want to use the `filter()` function to remove all the strings to leave just numbers.
I can do it the normal method, but I cant do it with the filter method...any tips?

so:

```
list(filter(type(i)==str,a)))
```

wouldn't work...I tried to use it, but that still doesn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    list(filter(type(a[-1])==str,a))
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Comment: Don't use variable names that shadow built-in names like `list`. That can lead to a variety of annoying problems later on (especially if you want to use `filter` on Python 3). Generally I see people using a trailing underscore `list_ =` or omitting the vocals `lst =` or appending a number `list1 =`. However you should aim to make the variable names as self-explaining as possible, which would mean to avoid naming lists as "list" altogether.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you could use `filter` for this, don't. You'd need a `lambda` function to do it, and it would be both slower and less readable than an equivalent list comprehension or generator expression. Instead, just use the listcomp or genexpr:

```
old_list = [1,2,3,'t',4,5,'fgt',6,7,'string']
new_list = [x for x in old_list if isinstance(x, (int, float))]
# or to remove str specifically, rather than preserve numeric:
new_list = [x for x in old_list if not isinstance(x, str)]
```

That's much more straightforward than the `filter`+`lambda` equivalent:

```
new_list = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)), old_list))
```

As noted in [COLDSPEED's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46396125/364696), to be generally accepting of all "number-alikes" you should actually use `isinstance` with `numbers.Number`; using `(int, float)` handles the literal types, but wouldn't handle `complex`, `fractions.Fraction`, `decimal.Decimal`, or third-party numeric types.

Comment: What makes you think they'd need a `lambda` function?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: A `def` function would be equivalent on added complexity and slower performance, and off-hand, there are no obvious and correct ways to delegate to a built-in function that could perform the test (that would at least conceivably run faster). `filter` is basically a micro-optimization in the C built-in case that's a pessimization in all other cases; you want a listcomp/genexpr 99% of the time.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I was speaking off-the-cuff; if I were to be technically accurate, I'd say "You'd need to write a custom function from scratch to do it". That said, 99% of the time, when people use `filter` with a custom function, they're using a one-off `lambda` function, even though `def` is equivalent, just named and potentially more powerful.

Comment: Thanks answered, how do i close this question now???? or what do i do to indicate that i am done?? is it always open? new here. thanks very much

Comment: @Agentπ: If your question is fully answered by one of the answers, just click the grey checkmark outline immediately underneath that answer's voting buttons to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a `filter`, you can shape your `lambda` to be a bit more elegant.

```
from numbers import Number
new_list = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, Number), old_list))
```

`numbers.Number` is an injected superclass of `int` and `float`, and `complex`. For real types, use `numbers.Real` instead.

Comment: Why not `numbers.Number` given that the condition is "keep numbers"? :)

Comment: @MSeifert That would include complex numbers... not sure how far OP thought this through, but edited anyway.

Comment: Note: Sadly, going from `numbers.Number` to `numbers.Real` will also exclude `decimal.Decimal`; for unclear reasons, possibly related to preventing code from blindly converting it to `float`, it is not registered as a `Real` or `Rational` type (even though it's logically as much a "real" type as `float`, and practically a rational number type with power of 10 denominators). So if you're looking for all non-complex numbers, you'd need to special-case `decimal.Decimal`, e.g. `isinstance(x, (Real, decimal.Decimal))`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you for the heads-up, I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

I used this example and it worked for me:

Create a function that takes a list of non-negative integers (positive) and strings and returns a new list with the strings filtered out.

```
oldlist = [1,2,'a','b']

def filter_list(p):
    newlist = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), oldlist))
    return newlist
```

It filters out any string and leaves only the 'int' (numbers). Here you have more cases to use instead of 'oldlist' >>>

- [1,2,'a','b'] = 1,2
- [1,'a','b',0,15] = 1,0,15
- [1,7,'af','1','123',123] = 1,7,123

Answer (score 0):

You can check for integers or floats using `isinstance`:

```
old_list = [1,2,3,'t',4,5,'fgt',6,7,'string']
new_list = list(filter(lambda x:isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float), old_list))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```